# Problems with simple calculator using html

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

Ive been trying my hand in html.
Basically I just have to input field and want to add the two numbers together and display it in one of the input field.

The two inputs:

```
<input type="text" id="Num1" name="One"> <br>
<input type="text" id="Num2" name="Two"> <br>
```

Function for addition:

```
function calc(a,  b) {
        c = a + b;
        document.getElementById("Num1").value = c;
}
```

Button click action:

```
<button onclick="calc(document.getElementsByName('One').value, 
                        document.getElementsByName('Two').value);">

    </button>
```

Output is "NaN", however if I used ElementById or ElementByName on function and button, nothing happens, if I put in defined numbers in calc() in the button part, I get the correct solution.

Full Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>The getElementById() Function</title>
    <script>

      function updateParagraphText(){
        let labelElement = document.getElementById('label');

        labelElement.innerText = 'You clicked the button!';
        
      }
      function calc(a,  b) {
        c = a + b;
        document.getElementById("Num1").value = c;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="label">
      Click the button.
    </p>
    <button onclick="calc(document.getElementsByName('One').value, document.getElementsByName('Two').value);">
    </button>
  </body>

  <form>
    <input type="text" id="Num1" name="One"> <br>
    <input type="text" id="Num2" name="Two"> <br>
  </form>
</html>
```

Comment: `getElementsByName` returns a **collection** of elements, not an element. Don't use this method. Use `getElementById` and provide the id. Secondly, `.value` returns a string, not a number. You should convert it to number before applying the `+` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you're having problems because `document.getElementsByName('One')` returns an array of elements (which contains only one element, yours).

You should try `document.getElementsByName('One')[0].value`.

Consider also casting the values to ints since those can be arbitrary strings by default.

See this working example: https://jsfiddle.net/wtpL2q80/9/

Answer (score 1):

you can use `document.getElementById('Num1').value` instead of `document.getElementsByName('One').value` and use `parseInt` to be able to sum them properly

Comment: when working with numbers you should always, always use `parseInt`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `getElementById`. The full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>The getElementById() Function</title>
    <script>
      function updateParagraphText(){
        let labelElement = document.getElementById('label');
        labelElement.innerText = 'You clicked the button!';
      }
      function calc(a,  b) {
        c = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
        document.getElementById("Num3").value = c;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="label">
      Click the button.
    </p>
    <button onclick="calc(document.getElementById('Num1').value, document.getElementById('Num2').value); updateParagraphText()">Button</button>
  </body>

  <form>
    <input type="text" id="Num1"> <br>
    <input type="text" id="Num2"> <br>
    <input type="text" id="Num3"> <br>
  </form>
</html>
```

I also corrected the values, because they were string instead of integers or float. Use `parseFloat` if it's the case. I also added a third input to input the see the result, but you can use the second (`Num2`) and remove the third.